# node.js tcp socket disconnect handling

Tags: node.js

I'm establishing a TCP client socket connection to an XMPP server and need a reliable way to detect interruptions in the connection (e.g. server crashes, restarts etc). I have listeners attached to the end, error and close events, but they do not fire reliably when I cut my internet connection during an active connection. How can my client detect when the connection has been broken?  I would prefer not to resort to pinging/timeouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in no way an expert on TCP or socket programming, but I'm pretty sure that there exists no "reliable way to detect interruptions in the connection". See e.g. [this Unix.com thread](http://www.unix.com/programming/78097-can-not-detect-tcp-disconnects-well.html).

In node, your options seem to be [socket.setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback)/[socket.on('timeout', callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_timeout) and/or [socket.setKeepAlive](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay).

**Edit:** Here is a guide on [TCP keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html).

Comment: but do you see, that socket.setTimeout can be used with keepalive packets?